# Paper-input inside paper-icon-item not permitting space?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I've run into a strange, and very recently introduced issue.  It seems that a paper-input element inside a paper-icon-item no longer permits a 'space' in its entry.  I have no idea why that is the case only inside a paper-icon-item, but here is the reproduction of the issue:

http://jsbin.com/herove/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been reported in Github repo here:   [github.com/PolymerElements/paper-item/issues/28](http://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-item/issues/28)

Also note that due to paper-item recently having button behaviour, it has caused other issues like tab-indexing, wherein the paper-item (or paper-icon-item) is now receiving focus on tab, rather than the paper-input inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

`paper-icon-item` is not a valid element. Maybe you have to declare it as a custom element somewhere first?

If you change `paper-icon-item` to `div` it works fine.

Comment: paper-icon-item is indeed a valid element.  It is a helper element provided by polymer team (it is a specialized type of paper-item).  It helps line things up with icons.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Didn't know `paper-icon-item` was a thing until checking the drop-down in the documentation of `paper-item`. 
There is a bug filled about your issue saying the space key is caught as a button activation so it doesn't work as a valid key for the input:
https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-item/issues/28

Comment: thanks for the heads up on the github issue.  It seems now that paper-item has become a button, this also causes other issues like tab indexing, wherein paper-item (or paper-icon-item) is now receiving focus on tab, instead of the paper-input inside it.